# delete XP from dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and windows XP in dual boot mode. I am ready to kick XP to the curb and only run Ubuntu. How do I do this and not lose my settings in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Ubuntu use os-uninstaller to install open terminal(ctrl+Alt+T)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/os-uninstaller

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install os-uninstaller
```

you can see how to do it here http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/03/os-uninstaller-grub-remover-ubuntu-linux/

or

you can also try this if you did not install Ubuntu with Wubi, then open Gparted and remove the xp partition(careful recheck before deleting, otherwise you may delete some other partition and may lose data) it wont effect the Ubuntu 14.04. after that run this command in terminal(ctrl+Alt+T)

> sudo update-grub

I recommend you to use the first one using os-uninstaller